# R Functions with variables

Tags: r, function, variables

I have a function where im trying to compare a dataframe column to a ref table of type character. I have downloaded some data from the Norwegian central statistics office with popular first names. I want to add a column to my data frame which is basically a 1 or a 0 if the name appears in the list (1 being a boy 0 being a girl). Im getting the following error with the code

```
*Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'x' not found*
```

Data frame is train.
Reference data is male_names

```
male_names <- read.csv("~/R/Functions_Practice/NO/BoysNames_Data.csv", sep=";",as.is = TRUE)[ ,1]

get.sex <- function(x, ref)
   for (i in ref)
   {
    if(x %in% ref)
    {return (1)}
   }

# set default for column
  train$sex <- 2
# Update column if it appears in the names list
  train$sex <- sapply(train$sex, FUN=get.sex(x,male_names))
```

I would then use the function to run the second Girls Name file against the table and set the flag for each record to zero where that occurs

Can anyone help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `sapply`, you don't write arguments directly in the `FUN` parameter.

```
train$sex <- sapply(train$sex, FUN=get.sex,ref = male_names)
```

It is implied that `train$sex` is the `x` argument, and all other parameters are passed after that (in this case, it's just `ref`) and are explicitly defined.

Edit:

As joran noted, in this case `sapply` isn't particularly useful, and you can do the results in one line:

```
train$sex = (train$sex %in% male_names)*1
```

`%in%` can be used when the argument on the left is a vector, so you don't have to loop over it.  Multiplying the result by one converts logical (boolean) values into integers.  `1*TRUE` yields `1`, and `1*FALSE` yields `0`.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that `sapply` isn't really necessary here, it seems. Could probably just vectorize it.

Comment: Good idea.  I made an edit above with that included.  It's still important to show what was wrong with the original code, though.

Comment: This is great, works much faster and more importantly works. Thanks guys. Its great when you see it actually working :)